# Troubles trying to convert string to char[][]

Tags: c++, string, char

I'm building a class named Board, that will get it's details from a txt file.

```
#define ROW 25;
#define COL 80;
class Board
{
    char _board[ROW][COL] = {0};

public:
    Board(string name); // our new constructor - reads map from file.
};
```

It receives string name, and tries to open a file with the specific name.
In case we are indeed in the right file, I want to read the chars from it, and copy them into a board.
I've been trying several things, that are summed up in this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
    Board::Board(string name)
{
    string line;
        ifstream file(name);
        int i = 0;
    if (file.is_open())
        {
            while (!file.eof())
            {
    
            (1) getline(file, line);
            (2) const char* test = line.c_str();
            (3) strcpy_s(_board[i], test);

        (4) _board[i] = line;

                    i++;

            }
// MORE FUNCTIONS NOT RELEVANT TO THIS QUESTION
        }
}
```

I get the following errors:
For (3): The program crashes.
For (4): expression must be a modifiable lvalue.
For (1), (2): test and line are worked well.

Is there any other simplier way to copy string to char* without using ugly loops, and copy every single char?
Why is (3) crashing my program?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)

Answer (score 1):

Unrelated, but `void main()` had been deprecated for ages and is incorrect in current versions of the standard: it shall be `int main()`...

Next `while (!file.eof())` is a common but terrible thing: `eof` becomes true only after a reading operation returned nothing. That means that you will process the last line twice...

For your errors:

- (4) _board[i] is an array, and an array cannot be on the left size of an assignment (idiomatically: it is not a *lvalue*)
- (3): `strcpy_s` is **not** a drop-in replacement for `strcpy` and your compiler should have emit warnings (any *correct* compiler would have...). It should be:

  ```
    strcpy_s(_board[i], COL, test);
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've updated the loop conditions, but strcpy_s(_board[i], COL, test) crashes my program. Even when using strcpy I'm getting CRT_SECURE warning, even when I'm defining it at the beginning of the page.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#define ROW 25;
#define COL 80;
int i=0;
class Board
{
    char _board[ROW][COL] = {0};

public:
    Board(string name); // our new constructor - reads map from file.
};
Board::Board(string name)
{
   fstream newfile;

   newfile.open(name,ios::in); 

   if (newfile.is_open()){   

      string tp;
      while(getline(newfile, tp)){ 
        strcpy(_board[i], tp);
        i++;
      }
      newfile.close(); 
   }
}
```

Comment: For this code I get the following error: "No suitable conversion function from std::string to const char * exists". Is there any include that I might be missing?